# Heroku Rails deployment gets rejected by gems that aren't in my gemfile or lockfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, deployment

I am creating a staging instance for an app that already runs on Heroku. I'm trying to push a specific branch to a brand new Heroku app via git in the terminal. After a long build process, Heroku rejects the push every single time due to mailcatcher and its dependency sqlite3.

I know that it doesn't support sqlite3, so I removed both gems from the gemfile. Then I deleted the lockfile. Ran bundle. Then bundle install. Commited everything to Git. The pushed to Heroku and again it gets rejected. Time and time again for the same two gems that I removed yesterday, and no matter how many times I try, it always sees them. Does anyone know how to get Heroku to notice that I have since removed the gems its complaining about?

Also, for thoroughness-sake I originally just tried moving them to the development group in the Gemfile, but again nothing. Heroku refuses to let it go.

No matter what I have tried, (moving it to development group, removing it entirely), Heroku always errors out trying to install mailcatcher and sqlite3. The gemfile and lockfile are below. Any ideas?

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.3'

# Rails Assets
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap-datepicker'
  gem 'rails-assets-html5shiv'
  gem 'rails-assets-jquery', '~> 1.11.0'
  gem 'rails-assets-jquery.slimscroll'
  gem 'rails-assets-mediaelement', '2.14.2' # tests fail in 2.15.0
  gem 'rails-assets-modernizr'
  gem 'rails-assets-respond'
end

gem 'bugsnag'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'devise', git: 'https://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git', branch: 'master'
gem 'dotenv-rails'
gem 'dynamic_form'
gem 'email_preview'
gem 'email_validator'
gem 'eventmachine', '~> 1.0.4'
gem 'filterrific', '~> 4.0'
gem 'fog'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'haml', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'html2haml'
gem 'humanize'
gem 'icalendar'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'mixpanel-ruby'
gem 'okcomputer'
gem 'pg'
gem 'placeholder-gem'
gem 'pry-rails'
gem 'puma'
gem 'pundit', '~> 1.0.0'
gem 'rack-timeout'
gem 'rails', '4.2.7.1'
gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap', '3.1.1' # boostrap tests fail in 3.2.0
gem 'rails-console-tweaks'
gem 'rqrcode'
gem 'sidekiq', '4.2.10'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'wisper'

# Administrate Dependencies
gem 'administrate', '~> 0.2.2'
gem 'bourbon', '4.2.7'
gem 'sass', '~> 3.4.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'coffee-script'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'jasmine-rails'
  gem 'rails-assets-jasmine-jquery'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '3.5.2'
end

group :debug do
  gem 'pry-remote'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'email_spec'
  gem 'factory_girl_rspec'
  gem 'pundit-matchers', '~> 1.0.0'
  gem 'rspec-core'
  gem 'rspec-lintable'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'timecop'
  gem 'vcr'
  gem 'webmock'
end

group :production, :staging do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
end

group :ct do
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-bundler'
  gem 'guard-jasmine-rails'
  gem 'guard-jshintrb'
  gem 'guard-livereload'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-rubocop'
  gem 'guard-sheller'
  gem 'terminal-notifier'
  gem 'terminal-notifier-guard'
end

# Continuous integration gems
# exclude from production codebase via BUNDLE_WITHOUT env variable
group :ci do
  gem 'brakeman'
  gem 'bundler-audit'
  gem 'jshintrb'
  gem 'rubocop'
end

# utility gems that add binaries but should not be included
# into the loaded application codebase.
# exclude from production codebase via BUNDLE_WITHOUT env variable
group :toolbox do
  gem 'bundler-reorganizer'
  gem 'bundler-updater'
  gem 'foreman'
  gem 'thegarage-gitx'
  gem 'travis'
end
```

Lockfile:

```
    GIT
  remote: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git
  revision: 6dd444458258c27ad08f56151e74fe9998713818
  branch: master
  specs:
    devise (3.4.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      responders
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  remote: https://rails-assets.org/
  specs:
    CFPropertyList (2.3.5)
    actionmailer (4.2.7.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.7.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.7.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.7.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.7.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.7.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.7.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    activejob (4.2.7.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.7.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.7.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.7.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.7.1)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.3.6)
    administrate (0.2.2)
      autoprefixer-rails (~> 6.0)
      datetime_picker_rails (~> 0.0.7)
      jquery-rails (~> 4.0)
      kaminari (~> 0.16)
      momentjs-rails (~> 2.8)
      neat (~> 1.1)
      normalize-rails (~> 3.0)
      rails (~> 4.2)
      sass-rails (~> 5.0)
      selectize-rails (~> 0.6)
    arel (6.0.4)
    ast (2.3.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (6.5.0.1)
      execjs
    backports (3.6.4)
    bcrypt (3.1.9)
    better_errors (2.1.1)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.6.6)
      rack (>= 0.9.0)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bourbon (4.2.7)
      sass (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.19)
    brakeman (3.5.0)
    bugsnag (5.3.3)
    builder (3.2.3)
    bundler-audit (0.3.1)
      bundler (~> 1.2)
      thor (~> 0.18)
    bundler-reorganizer (1.1.1)
      thor
    bundler-updater (0.0.3)
      thor
    capybara (2.4.4)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    carrierwave (1.1.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    chunky_png (1.3.8)
    coderay (1.1.1)
    coffee-script (2.3.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.8.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
    connection_pool (2.2.1)
    crack (0.4.2)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0.0)
    datetime_picker_rails (0.0.7)
      momentjs-rails (>= 2.8.1)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    diff-lcs (1.3)
    docile (1.1.5)
    dotenv (1.0.2)
    dotenv-rails (1.0.2)
      dotenv (= 1.0.2)
    dynamic_form (1.1.4)
    em-websocket (0.5.1)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.9)
      http_parser.rb (~> 0.6.0)
    email_preview (1.5.4)
      rails (>= 3.0)
    email_spec (1.6.0)
      launchy (~> 2.1)
      mail (~> 2.2)
    email_validator (1.5.0)
      activemodel
    erubis (2.7.0)
    ethon (0.7.2)
      ffi (>= 1.3.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.9.1)
    excon (0.56.0)
    execjs (2.2.2)
    factory_girl (4.5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.5.0)
      factory_girl (~> 4.5.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rspec (2.1.0)
      factory_girl (>= 2.0)
      rspec (>= 2.0)
    faraday (0.9.1)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    faraday_middleware (0.9.1)
      faraday (>= 0.7.4, < 0.10)
    ffi (1.9.17)
    filterrific (4.0.0)
    fission (0.5.0)
      CFPropertyList (~> 2.2)
    fog (1.40.0)
      fog-aliyun (>= 0.1.0)
      fog-atmos
      fog-aws (>= 0.6.0)
      fog-brightbox (~> 0.4)
      fog-cloudatcost (~> 0.1.0)
      fog-core (~> 1.43)
      fog-digitalocean (>= 0.3.0)
      fog-dnsimple (~> 1.0)
      fog-dynect (~> 0.0.2)
      fog-ecloud (~> 0.1)
      fog-google (<= 0.1.0)
      fog-json
      fog-local
      fog-openstack
      fog-powerdns (>= 0.1.1)
      fog-profitbricks
      fog-rackspace
      fog-radosgw (>= 0.0.2)
      fog-riakcs
      fog-sakuracloud (>= 0.0.4)
      fog-serverlove
      fog-softlayer
      fog-storm_on_demand
      fog-terremark
      fog-vmfusion
      fog-voxel
      fog-vsphere (>= 0.4.0)
      fog-xenserver
      fog-xml (~> 0.1.1)
      ipaddress (~> 0.5)
      json (>= 1.8, < 2.0)
    fog-aliyun (0.1.0)
      fog-core (~> 1.27)
      fog-json (~> 1.0)
      ipaddress (~> 0.8)
      xml-simple (~> 1.1)
    fog-atmos (0.1.0)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-aws (1.3.0)
      fog-core (~> 1.38)
      fog-json (~> 1.0)
      fog-xml (~> 0.1)
      ipaddress (~> 0.8)
    fog-brightbox (0.11.0)
      fog-core (~> 1.22)
      fog-json
      inflecto (~> 0.0.2)
    fog-cloudatcost (0.1.2)
      fog-core (~> 1.36)
      fog-json (~> 1.0)
      fog-xml (~> 0.1)
      ipaddress (~> 0.8)
    fog-core (1.44.3)
      builder
      excon (~> 0.49)
      formatador (~> 0.2)
    fog-digitalocean (0.3.0)
      fog-core (~> 1.42)
      fog-json (>= 1.0)
      fog-xml (>= 0.1)
      ipaddress (>= 0.5)
    fog-dnsimple (1.0.0)
      fog-core (~> 1.38)
      fog-json (~> 1.0)
    fog-dynect (0.0.3)
      fog-core
      fog-json
      fog-xml
    fog-ecloud (0.3.0)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-google (0.1.0)
      fog-core
      fog-json
      fog-xml
    fog-json (1.0.2)
      fog-core (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.10)
    fog-local (0.3.1)
      fog-core (~> 1.27)
    fog-openstack (0.1.21)
      fog-core (>= 1.40)
      fog-json (>= 1.0)
      ipaddress (>= 0.8)
    fog-powerdns (0.1.1)
      fog-core (~> 1.27)
      fog-json (~> 1.0)
      fog-xml (~> 0.1)
    fog-profitbricks (3.0.0)
      fog-core (~> 1.42)
      fog-json (~> 1.0)
    fog-rackspace (0.1.5)
      fog-core (>= 1.35)
      fog-json (>= 1.0)
      fog-xml (>= 0.1)
      ipaddress (>= 0.8)
    fog-radosgw (0.0.5)
      fog-core (>= 1.21.0)
      fog-json
      fog-xml (>= 0.0.1)
    fog-riakcs (0.1.0)
      fog-core
      fog-json
      fog-xml
    fog-sakuracloud (1.7.5)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    fog-serverlove (0.1.2)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    fog-softlayer (1.1.4)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    fog-storm_on_demand (0.1.1)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    fog-terremark (0.1.0)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-vmfusion (0.1.0)
      fission
      fog-core
    fog-voxel (0.1.0)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-vsphere (1.10.0)
      fog-core
      rbvmomi (~> 1.9)
    fog-xenserver (0.3.0)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-xml (0.1.3)
      fog-core
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.11, < 2.0.0)
    font-awesome-rails (4.2.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.0)
    foreman (0.78.0)
      thor (~> 0.19.1)
    formatador (0.2.5)
    gh (0.14.0)
      addressable
      backports
      faraday (~> 0.8)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      net-http-persistent (>= 2.7)
      net-http-pipeline
    globalid (0.3.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    guard (2.14.0)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      lumberjack (~> 1.0)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      notiffany (~> 0.0)
      pry (>= 0.9.12)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
      thor (>= 0.18.1)
    guard-bundler (2.1.0)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      guard (~> 2.2)
      guard-compat (~> 1.1)
    guard-compat (1.2.1)
    guard-jasmine-rails (1.1.4)
      guard (>= 2.0)
    guard-jshintrb (1.1.0)
      guard (~> 2.0)
      jshintrb
    guard-livereload (2.4.0)
      em-websocket (~> 0.5)
      guard (~> 2.8)
      multi_json (~> 1.8)
    guard-rspec (4.7.3)
      guard (~> 2.1)
      guard-compat (~> 1.1)
      rspec (>= 2.99.0, < 4.0)
    guard-rubocop (1.2.0)
      guard (~> 2.0)
      rubocop (~> 0.20)
    guard-sheller (1.0.2)
      guard (>= 2.0)
    haml (4.0.7)
      tilt
    high_voltage (2.2.1)
    highline (1.7.8)
    html2haml (2.1.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      haml (~> 4.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6.0)
      ruby_parser (~> 3.5)
    http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
    humanize (1.3.0)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    icalendar (2.4.1)
    inflecto (0.0.2)
    ipaddress (0.8.3)
    jasmine-core (2.1.3)
    jasmine-rails (0.10.6)
      jasmine-core (>= 1.3, < 3.0)
      phantomjs
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
      sprockets-rails
    jquery-rails (4.0.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jshintrb (0.2.4)
      execjs
      multi_json (>= 1.3)
      rake
    json (1.8.6)
    kaminari (0.17.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    launchy (2.4.3)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    lumberjack (1.0.11)
    mail (2.6.4)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (3.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
    mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
    minitest (5.10.1)
    mixpanel-ruby (1.6.0)
    momentjs-rails (2.15.1)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    multi_json (1.12.1)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    neat (1.8.0)
      sass (>= 3.3)
      thor (~> 0.19)
    nenv (0.3.0)
    net-http-persistent (2.9.4)
    net-http-pipeline (1.0.1)
    nokogiri (1.7.0.1)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.1.0)
    normalize-rails (3.0.3)
    notiffany (0.1.1)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
    octokit (3.7.0)
      sawyer (~> 0.6.0, >= 0.5.3)
    okcomputer (1.1.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    parser (2.3.3.1)
      ast (~> 2.2)
    pg (0.18.1)
    phantomjs (1.9.8.0)
    placeholder-gem (3.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    powerpack (0.1.1)
    pry (0.10.4)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8.1)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    pry-rails (0.3.2)
      pry (>= 0.9.10)
    pry-remote (0.1.8)
      pry (~> 0.9)
      slop (~> 3.0)
    puma (3.6.2)
    pundit (1.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    pundit-matchers (1.0.0)
      pundit (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.0)
      rspec (~> 3.0, >= 3.0.0)
      rspec-rails (~> 3.0, >= 3.0.0)
    pusher-client (0.6.0)
      json
      websocket (~> 1.0)
    rack (1.6.8)
    rack-protection (1.5.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rack-timeout (0.2.0)
    rails (4.2.7.1)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.7.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.7.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.7.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.7.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.7.1)
      activerecord (= 4.2.7.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.7.1)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-assets-bootstrap (3.1.1)
      rails-assets-jquery (>= 1.9.0)
    rails-assets-bootstrap-datepicker (1.3.1)
      rails-assets-bootstrap (>= 3.0, < 4.0)
      rails-assets-jquery (>= 1.7.1)
    rails-assets-html5shiv (3.7.2)
    rails-assets-jasmine-jquery (2.0.4)
    rails-assets-jquery (1.11.2)
    rails-assets-jquery.slimscroll (1.3.3)
      rails-assets-jquery (>= 1.7)
    rails-assets-mediaelement (2.14.2)
    rails-assets-modernizr (2.8.3)
    rails-assets-respond (1.4.2)
    rails-console-tweaks (1.0.2)
      rails (>= 3.0)
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.8)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.3)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
    railties (4.2.7.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.7.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rainbow (2.2.1)
    rake (12.0.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.8)
    rb-inotify (0.9.7)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rbvmomi (1.11.2)
      builder (~> 3.0)
      json (>= 1.8)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)
      trollop (~> 2.1)
    redis (3.3.3)
    responders (2.0.2)
      railties (>= 4.2.0.alpha, < 5)
    rqrcode (0.10.1)
      chunky_png (~> 1.0)
    rspec (3.5.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.5.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.5.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.5.0)
    rspec-core (3.5.4)
      rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.5.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
    rspec-lintable (1.0.1)
      jshintrb
      rspec
    rspec-mocks (3.5.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
    rspec-rails (3.5.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.5.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.5.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.5.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
    rspec-support (3.5.0)
    rubocop (0.47.1)
      parser (>= 2.3.3.1, < 3.0)
      powerpack (~> 0.1)
      rainbow (>= 1.99.1, < 3.0)
      ruby-progressbar (~> 1.7)
      unicode-display_width (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    ruby-progressbar (1.8.1)
    ruby_dep (1.3.1)
    ruby_parser (3.8.4)
      sexp_processor (~> 4.1)
    rugged (0.21.4)
    safe_yaml (1.0.4)
    sass (3.4.23)
    sass-rails (5.0.6)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sawyer (0.6.0)
      addressable (~> 2.3.5)
      faraday (~> 0.8, < 0.10)
    selectize-rails (0.12.3)
    sexp_processor (4.8.0)
    shellany (0.0.1)
    shoulda-matchers (2.7.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    sidekiq (4.2.10)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      connection_pool (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.0)
      rack-protection (>= 1.5.0)
      redis (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.1)
    simplecov (0.9.1)
      docile (~> 1.1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.8.0)
    simplecov-html (0.8.0)
    slop (3.6.0)
    spring (1.2.0)
    spring-commands-rspec (1.0.4)
      spring (>= 0.9.1)
    sprockets (3.7.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    terminal-notifier (1.6.2)
    terminal-notifier-guard (1.6.4)
    thegarage-gitx (2.12.0)
      octokit
      rugged (~> 0.21.0)
      thor
    thor (0.19.4)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    timecop (0.7.1)
    travis (1.6.11)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
      backports
      faraday (~> 0.9)
      faraday_middleware (~> 0.9)
      gh (~> 0.13)
      highline (~> 1.6)
      launchy (~> 2.1)
      pry (~> 0.9)
      pusher-client (~> 0.4)
      typhoeus (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.8)
    trollop (2.1.2)
    typhoeus (0.7.0)
      ethon (>= 0.7.1)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.7.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    unicode-display_width (1.1.3)
    vcr (2.9.3)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    webmock (1.20.4)
      addressable (>= 2.3.6)
      crack (>= 0.3.2)
    websocket (1.2.1)
    wisper (1.6.0)
    xml-simple (1.1.5)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  administrate (~> 0.2.2)
  better_errors
  binding_of_caller
  bourbon (= 4.2.7)
  brakeman
  bugsnag
  bundler-audit
  bundler-reorganizer
  bundler-updater
  capybara
  carrierwave
  coffee-script
  devise!
  dotenv-rails
  dynamic_form
  email_preview
  email_spec
  email_validator
  eventmachine (~> 1.0.4)
  factory_girl_rails
  factory_girl_rspec
  filterrific (~> 4.0)
  fog
  font-awesome-rails
  foreman
  guard
  guard-bundler
  guard-jasmine-rails
  guard-jshintrb
  guard-livereload
  guard-rspec
  guard-rubocop
  guard-sheller
  haml (~> 4.0.3)
  high_voltage
  html2haml
  humanize
  icalendar
  jasmine-rails
  jquery-rails
  jshintrb
  kaminari
  mixpanel-ruby
  okcomputer
  pg
  placeholder-gem
  pry-rails
  pry-remote
  puma
  pundit (~> 1.0.0)
  pundit-matchers (~> 1.0.0)
  rack-timeout
  rails (= 4.2.7.1)
  rails-assets-bootstrap (= 3.1.1)
  rails-assets-bootstrap-datepicker!
  rails-assets-html5shiv!
  rails-assets-jasmine-jquery
  rails-assets-jquery (~> 1.11.0)!
  rails-assets-jquery.slimscroll!
  rails-assets-mediaelement (= 2.14.2)!
  rails-assets-modernizr!
  rails-assets-respond!
  rails-console-tweaks
  rails_12factor
  rqrcode
  rspec-core
  rspec-lintable
  rspec-rails (= 3.5.2)
  rubocop
  sass (~> 3.4.0)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0.0)
  shoulda-matchers
  sidekiq (= 4.2.10)
  simplecov
  spring
  spring-commands-rspec
  terminal-notifier
  terminal-notifier-guard
  thegarage-gitx
  timecop
  travis
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  vcr
  webmock
  wisper

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.3.3p222

BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.1
```

Comment: Please post the error from your deploy log.

Answer (score 0):

Try these things:

- Check your database yml file, probably it requires sqlite
- Add the specific require version of the pg gem like this:

  `group :production do
      gem 'pg', '~> 0.20'
    end`
- `git grep sqlite`, To see if there is any remnants of sqlite

Comment: Looking at it now, just to be sure, and its all postgres.

Comment: Check the updated answear, the pg gem version can be the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

try moving mailcatcher and sqlite3 under the development section of your gem file.

```
group :development do
  gem 'mailcatcher'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  ....
end
```

Because heroku runs your env as production and don't like to have development gems E.g sqlite3 in the production / common section.